# Scrapy - Sometimes extract data from subsite

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm parsing a website and I want to extract some data about authors. Because a few authors write a lot of articles, I save the authors info into a database. Only if I don't have info about a new author I want to crawl a sub-site to extract the data and then save them into the database. I've read a lot of document about how to extract data from another website but I can't make it works. I'am fairly new to Python and don't get all the differences between return and yield.

Here's part of my code :

```
def start_requests(self):
    for url in self.getUrlsToCrawl():
        yield self.buildRequest(url[1], url[0])


def buildRequest(self, url, dbid):
     return SplashRequest(url, self.parse,
             endpoint='execute',
             cache_args=['lua_source'],
             args={'lua_source':script, 'image':0},
             meta={'dbId': dbid, 'originalUrl': url},
             errback=self.errback_httpbin, dont_filter=True)

def parse(self, response):
    [...]
    articleLoader.add_value('authors', self.getAuthors(response))
    [...]
    return articleLoader.load_item()

def getAuthors(self, response):
     authorsArray = []
     authorName = remove_tags(response.xpath(myxpath).extract_first())
     authorUrl = response.xpath(myxpath).extract_first()
     authorInfos = self.executeSQL('SELECT name, twitter, email FROM author WHERE LOWER(name) = LOWER(%s) and domain = %s', (authorName, self.domain, ))
     authorItem = AuthorItem()
     if len(authorInfos) != 0:
         authorItem['name'] = authorInfos[0][0]
         authorItem['twitter'] = authorInfos[0][1]
         authorItem['email'] = authorInfos[0][2]
     elif authorUrl:
         self.fetchAuthorInfos(authorUrl, authorItem)
     else:
        authorItem['name'] = authorName

     authorsArray.append(dict(authorItem))
     return authorsArray

 def fetchAuthorInfos(self, url, authorItem):
     return SplashRequest(url, callback = self.parseAuthorInfos, meta={'item':authorItem})

 def parseAuthorInfos(self, response):
     authorItem = response.meta['item']
     authorItem['name'] = 'toto'
     authorItem['twitter'] = 'titi'
     authorItem['email'] = 'maimai'
     return authorItem
```

I (randomly) tried different combinations between return and yield. Sometimes I reach `fetchAuthorInfos`, sometimes not but I never reach `parseAuthorInfos`. If the info of the author is in my database or if I don't have the personal author url to fetch everything works fine.

Thanks for the help!

**Edit**
Thanks to Granitosaurus I found a way around but I'm still not 100% satisfied because sometimes I can have several authors for an article and I'd like to be able to extract the info for everybody

```
def parse(self, response):
    [...]
    return self.get_authors(response, articleLoader)

def get_authors(self, response, articleLoader):
    [...]
    elif authorUrl:
        return Request(authorUrl, callback = self.parse_author_infos, meta={'item':articleLoader})
    else:
        authorLoader.add_value('name', authorName)

    authorsArray.append(dict(authorLoader.load_item()))
    articleLoader.add_value('authors', authorsArray)
    return articleLoader.load_item()

def parse_author_infos(self, response):
    [...]
    return articleLoader.load_item()
```

Comment: You should really familiarize with [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), e.g. use snake_case instead of pascalCase.

Comment: I will definitely have a look, I'm more used to java

Answer (score 0):

This line pretty much does nothing:

```
self.fetchAuthorInfos(author_url, author_item)
```

The function returns SplashRequest but it's not assigned, returned or used in any way.

You're missing the chain logic here. What you want to do is to continue the request chain to the author's page, like:

```
def parse(self, response):
    """This parses article's page"""
    article_loader = ArticleLoader(response)
    # add some stuff to article loader
    <...>

    author_url = 'some_url'  
    if author_url:
        # if there's url to author page scrape that url for authors info
        return SplashRequest(url, callback=self.parse_author, 
                             meta={'item': article_loader.load_item()})
    # otherwise just scrape presented author info
    author_item = dict()
    author_item['name'] = 'foobar'
    article_loader.add_value('author', author_item) 
    return article_loader.load_item()


 def parse_author(self, response):
    """This parses author's page"""
    article_loader = response.meta['item']
    author_item['name'] = 'toto'
    author_item['twitter'] = 'titi'
    author_item['email'] = 'maimai'
    aritcle_loader.add_value('author', author_item)
    return article_loader
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I changed to `elif authorUrl:
             return Request(authorUrl, callback = self.parseAuthorInfos, meta={'item':authorItem})` but now my main item is now  like  `{'authors': [<GET URL>]` where URL is the url from authorUrl. Furthemore I still can't see the print i put in `parseAuthorInfos`

Comment: @RogerFromSpace could you try adding `dont_filter=True` parameter to this request? i.e. `Request(dont_filter=True)`. It could be that your request is being filtered out since you've already visited the url during the crawl session.

Comment: @RogerFromSpace could you post the crawl log? You can generate one by typing this: `scrapy crawl myspider &> output.log`

Comment: http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/54WR not much help i'm afraid. I changed all the data

Comment: @RogerFromSpace alright, I think I'm getting a gist of logic here. What you should do is merge `parse` and `getAuthors` methods. All you need is one method for parsing the article page that either returns an item(if no author url is present) or returns another request to authors page. See my edit to the code :)

Comment: thanks to you I found a way, I edited my original question but still not 100 satisfied